# Remove all TableRows from an ASP.NET Table

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web

I have an `ASP.NET` server side table and I want to delete the rows from it. I'm trying to do this using the following.

```
For Each myRw As TableRow In tblDays.Rows
    tblDays.Rows.Remove(myRw)
Next
```

I get an enumeration error. I wondered if anyone new of a good approach to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot modify a collection during enumeration(`foreach`). Modifying means that you cannot add, delete or replace an item. You either have to use a  `for` or `while` loop or simply [`Table.Rows.Clear`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.tablerowcollection.clear%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
tblDays.Rows.Clear()
```

Here's the for-loop ( you need to loop backwards )

```
For i As Int32 = tblDays.Rows.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
    tblDays.Rows.RemoveAt(i)
Next
```

and here the while-loop

```
While tblDays.Rows.Count > 0
    tblDays.Rows.RemoveAt(0)
End While
```

Answer (score 1):

`ForEach` works with the enumerator and you cannot modify the enumerator within the `ForEach` loop.

Do the following to achieve what you want

```
For i AS Integer = tblDays.Rows.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
    tblDays.Rows.RemoveAt(i)
Next
```

or you can clear the rows collection

```
tblDays.Rows.Clear()
```